# How to randomise wordpress posts across multiple categories, in this case over 5,000 meme posts?

Tags: wordpress

Google search provided no answers at all on how to randomise over 4k meme posts that are displayed in a masonary style layout with infinite loading not unlike a pinterest page.
By adding the question here and the solution google will display it for others looking for this simple solution that I worked out as a 'non coder'. I can do basic code and a lot of copy paste but not like you guys can do which much of it is over my head. 
But over the years I've found lots of solutions on this forum and thus want to give back, especially for your non coder visitors like myself looking for a solution they can get their head around.

Answer (score 0):

So how did I do it.....

1. Upload all images useing plugin called - Bulk Images to Posts
2. Export all posts with export plugin called - wp all export and save as excel spread sheet.
3. manipulate spread sheet by selecting column containing post ID number data
4. randomize (vids on how to on youtube) the ID's column in excel and thus every post
5. import back in with plugin called - wp all import
6. done, now all 5k posts are random on my blog home page.